# Bound on $f'(i)$ for $f:\text{UHP} \to \text{ region right of a hyperbola }$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> Denote $$H=\{z=x+iy: x,y\in \mathbb{R}, y>0\}, \quad
>  \text{and}\\[12pt]V=\{z=x+iy: x^2-y^2>1, x>0\}.$$
>
> Let $$\mathcal{S} = \{f:H\to V, \,\,f \text{ is holomorphic and }
>  f(i)=2\}.$$
>
> Find all the functions $g\in \mathcal{S}$ such that $|f'(i)|\leq
>  |g'(i)|$ for all $f\in \mathcal{S}$. Compute $g'(i)$.

**Ideas:** Suppose we have $\varphi: \mathbb{D}\to H:0\mapsto i$ and $\psi: V\to \mathbb{D}:2\mapsto 0$. Then we can reason by Schwarz's lemma somehow, but I'm not seeing a bound on $\{f'(i)\mid f\in H\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is exactly right (assuming you mean $\psi$ and $\varphi$ to be conformal maps onto the corresponding 
domains). By the chain rule, the derivative of the composition $\psi\circ f\circ \varphi$ at $0$ is 
$$ \varphi'(0) \, f'(i)\, \psi'(2)$$
By the Schwarz lemma, this is at most $1$ in absolute value. Hence, 
$$|f'(i)|\le \frac{1}{|\varphi'(0)\psi'(2)|}\tag{1}$$
Equality is attained in (1) if and only if $\psi\circ f\circ \varphi$ is a rotation, which means there is real 
constant $\alpha$ such that 
$$f(z)= \psi^{-1}(e^{i\alpha} \varphi^{-1}(z)),\quad z\in H  \tag{2}$$
This   identifies the set of functions $f$ which maximize $|f'(i)|$. Of course,  without concrete   $\psi$ and $\varphi$ this is not sufficiently explicit. Also, we need $\psi$ and $\varphi$ to find the value of the maximum.

To find  $\varphi$ is standard:
$$\varphi(z)=i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$$
As for $\psi$, note that $x^2-y^2$ is the real part of $z^2$. Thus, $z\mapsto z^2-1$ sends $V$ onto the right halfplane. 
From there it's standard:
$$\psi(z) = \frac{(z^2-1)-3}{(z^2-1)+3}$$

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. In evaluating the maximum, how do we know that $\varphi'(0)$ and $\psi'(2)$ do not vary with different choices of $\varphi, \psi$?

Comment: @EricAuld One possible answer: why care? Having picked  some $\varphi$ and $\psi$, like those above, we have solved the problem: found the maximum of $|f'(i)|$, and identified the functions attaining it. Case closed. Second answer: the derivatives vary, but their absolute values do not. Namely, for any two simply-connected domains $D_1,D_2$ with chosen points $z_j\in D_j$ all conformal maps $\phi$ of $D_1$ onto $D_2$ such that $\phi(z_1)=z_2$ have the same $|\phi'(z_1)|$. This is again a consequence of the Schwarz lemma. Take two such maps $\phi,\psi$ and form a suitable composition.

Comment: OK. Maybe my understanding is flawed: I'm not seeing how we have found the maximum over all $f\in \mathcal{S}$ if we have that the maximum is $$\frac1{\varphi'(0)\psi'(2)}.$$ A priori we don't know that some choices of $\psi$ might not make $\psi'(2)$ arbitrarily small, and so there may be no maximum of $f'(i)$. Of course your second answer takes care of this. But I assume the proof of the result mentioned in the second answer relies on a similar argument, so I am interested to know where is my error.

Comment: @EricAuld OK, I still emphasize that the first  answer is legit. The question is: find the number $M=\max |f'(i)|$ and identify the set of extremals $\mathcal E = \{g\}$. There is no $\varphi$ or $\psi$ here. If I decide to introduce some maps $\varphi$ and $\psi$  as auxiliary devices, I get to choose what they are, and nobody can tell me that I should have considered some other choices. I decided to use the maps $\varphi$ and $\psi$ given by explicit formulas above, and I don't need to care at all that other choices could be made.

Comment: @EricAuld On a less rhetorical level, I could begin the proof with: "Let $\varphi(z)=i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ and $\psi(z) = \frac{(z^2-1)-3}{(z^2-1)+3}$. Applying the Schwarz lemma to $\psi\circ f\circ \phi$, we find $|f'(i)|\le \dots$. Equality is attained if and only if $f = \dots$". With this style,  auxiliary maps are fixed right away and the "choices" issue does not even arise.

Comment: @EricAuld OK, one more remark. The problem is not just about estimating $|f'(i)|$ from above, it is about finding the supremum of $|f'(i)|$ over some class. Call this supremum $M$. The number $M$ is  yet unknown, but it is  determined by the setup of the problem. The process of finding $M$  may involve some choices; but as long as the logical steps are valid, you will necessarily arrive at the same value of $M$. This is just logic, not complex analysis or any kind of analysis.

Comment: Great! I understand now. I have a question about how to prove that any conformal maps $D_1 \to D_2$ with $\phi(z_1)=z_2$ have the same $|\phi'(z_1)|$. By the Riemann mapping theorem, we pre- and post-compose so that we have a map from the disc to the disc and $0\mapsto z_1 \mapsto z_2\mapsto 0$. Now how do we determine $|\phi'(z_1)|$? I see that we can get an inequality, like we did above...

Comment: @EricAuld The composition is not just any map from disk to disk. It is a conformal automorphism (holomorphic bijection). The Schwarz lemma applies both ways: to the map and its inverse. The composition is just a rotation of the disk.